# Building a List in Prolog

Tags: prolog

It's my first time programming with Prolog and I have some trouble grasping how the language is to be used exactly. I'm building a program that analyses a puzzle and returns a list of actions (path) that solves the puzzle. Here's a pretty simplified version of how it looks like:

```
puzzle(Size,start(StartX,StartY),goal(GoalX,GoalY),Clues,Path) :-
  solve(Size,StartX,StartY,XX,YY,Turns,Clues,GoalX,GoalY,[field(StartX,StartY)],Path).

solve(Size,X,Y,XX,YY,Turns,Clues,GoalX,GoalY,Visited,Path) :-
  X=GoalX, Y=GoalY,!;     
  Turns == 0, neighbor(X,Y,XX,YY), append(link(X,Y,XX,YY),Path,Newpath), solve(Size,XX,YY,XXX,YYY,Turns,Clues,GoalX,GoalY,Visited,Newpath);
  Turns > 1, turn(X,Y,XX,YY), append(link(X,Y,XX,YY), Path, Newpath), solve(Size,XX,YY,XXX,YYY,Turns,Clues,GoalX,GoalY,Visited,Newpath).
```

I create the path by recursively calling the solve function and appending a certain action to the path incrementally with every new call until the goal is reached. Now my problem is that the last recursive call has the path I'm looking for, however if I ask

```
?- puzzle(3, start(1,1), goal(3,3), [clue(2,1,2),clue(2,2,2)],Path)
```

it doesn't return that path. To illustrate:

```
   Exit: (13) solve(3, 3, 2, 0, 1, _G1027, _G1028, 1, 0, 1, [clue(2, 2, 2)], 3, 3, [feld(3, 2), feld(3, 1), feld(2, 1), feld(1, 1)], [link(3, 1, 3, 2), link(2, 1, 3, 1), link(1, 1, 2, 1), _G1012]) ? creep
```

[link(3, 1, 3, 2), link(2, 1, 3, 1), link(1, 1, 2, 1), _G1012] is the path I need.

```
   Exit: (12) move2(3, 3, 1, 1, 0, _G1027, _G1028, 1, 0, 2, [clue(2, 2, 2)], 3, 3, [feld(3, 1), feld(2, 1), feld(1, 1)], [link(2, 1, 3, 1), link(1, 1, 2, 1), _G1012]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) solve(3, 3, 1, 1, 0, _G1027, _G1028, _G1029, _G1030, 2, [clue(2, 2, 2)], 3, 3, [feld(3, 1), feld(2, 1), feld(1, 1)], [link(2, 1, 3, 1), link(1, 1, 2, 1), _G1012]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) stepfromclue(3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, [clue(2, 2, 2)], 3, 3, [feld(2, 1), feld(1, 1)], [link(1, 1, 2, 1), _G1012]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) checkclue(3, 2, 1, 1, 0, [clue(2, 1, 2), clue(2, 2, 2)], 3, 3, [feld(2, 1), feld(1, 1)], [link(1, 1, 2, 1), _G1012]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) solve(3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, _G1029, _G1030, 0, [clue(2, 1, 2), clue(2, 2, 2)], 3, 3, [feld(1, 1)], [_G1012]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) puzzle(3, start(1, 1), goal(3, 3), [clue(2, 1, 2), clue(2, 2, 2)], [_G1012]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) puzzle(1, [_G1012]) ? creep
```

Path = [_G1012] is the path I get. I seriously can't wrap my head around how I could "ask" for the path I need without completely rewriting the program.

Comment: It doesn't exactly get lost in checkclue. It's just that solve has a line that says: append([link(X,Y,XX,YY)],Path,Newpath), followed by checkclue(Size,XX,YY,DX,DY,Clues,GoalX,GoalY,Newbesucht,Newpath). As a result when checkclue is called it has the earlier path with one more link. Checkclue itself then leads to another link being added to the path etc etc.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include more of the program? I must have guessed incorrectly, but without seeing more of the program, I think it'll hard for others to spot the problem too.

Comment: I've edited the post with a bit more code that should be representative of my program. But really, I feel like the issue might just seem to simple to understand. Because it's apparent to me WHAT the mistake is: When I call the solve function recursively it doesnt return any value apart from true. So if I added write(Path) after X=GoalX, Y=GoalY,! it would write the correct path for me. But if I want it to return it in place of Path when I ask ?- puzzle(3, start(1,1), goal(3,3), [clue(2,1,2)],Path) it doesnt work. For it to work I need to change the program and I just cant understand how.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full code (including the `link/4` facts) it's a little hard to guess, since I can't trace the program myself. But I think the problem is the following:

What you attempt to do is construct the path iteratively by appending links to the path, creating a new path in variable `NewPath`:

```
append(link(X,Y,XX,YY),Path,Newpath),
```

There are two problems here. The first is, that `link(X,Y,XX,YY)` is not a list, so `append/3` will fail. The second, more important, is that `Path` is the input variable, `NewPath` the output, but you pass `NewPath` only down to the next call of `solve/11`, but not up. This way, the full path is never passed back to the caller. Thus, back at the level of the `puzzle/5` call, the `Path` variable stays uninstantiated.

Your code for `solve` should probably look more like this:

```
solve(_,X,Y,_,_,_,_,GoalX,GoalY,_,Path,Path) :-
    X=GoalX, Y=GoalY,!.
solve(Size,X,Y,XX,YY,Turns,Clues,GoalX,GoalY,Visited,PathIn,Path) :-
    Turns == 0, 
    neighbor(X,Y,XX,YY), 
    append(PathIn,[link(X,Y,XX,YY)],PathOut), 
    solve(Size,XX,YY,XXX,YYY,Turns,Clues,GoalX,GoalY,Visited,PathOut,Path).
solve(Size,X,Y,XX,YY,Turns,Clues,GoalX,GoalY,Visited,PathIn,Path) :-
    turn(X,Y,XX,YY), 
    append(PathIn,[link(X,Y,XX,YY)],PathOut), 
    solve(Size,XX,YY,XXX,YYY,Turns,Clues,GoalX,GoalY,Visited,PathOut,Path).
```

It could be simplified further, though.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I didn't know how to pass the variable up. This is a really nice way to do it, thanks a lot. Only question I have left is what you mean with simplifying it further?

Comment: In your code, the parameters `Size`, `Clues`, and `Visited` are never used, so they could be removed. Although it might well be that you edited out the calls where they were used. Likewise, the `XXX` and `YYY` parameters in the recursive `solve` calls. Finally, the last two lines of clause two and three are identical, so you could merge the two clauses using `( Turns == 0 -> neighbour(...) ; turn(...) ), append(...`